# Screen dpi and size on Samsung Galaxy S i9000

Tags: android, screen

does anybody know anything about the Samsung Galaxy S and screen density?

My calculations are that the Samsung S has a 233 dpi display, and Wikipedia agrees.  However, the device claims to have a pixel density of 320 dpi.  This causes the 480x800 display to be computed as 1.5" x 2.5" which is classified as a small display.  This in turn causes resources to be taken from values-small and all drawables to be scaled by 2x when it should be 1.5x.

Source code for a simple test program can be found at http://www.efalk.org/SamsungS.tar.gz (it's only a few lines of code).  Anybody with a Samsung S (or emulator) can see that the framework considers this a small screen.  I also see other artifacts not related to my program such as huge icons on the home screen and huge text in menus.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this truly a bug on the Samsung S?  If I'm doing something wrong, what should I be doing differently?

ETA: the source isn't that big, so I'm just adding it here:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.efalk.testsamsungs"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="2"
      android:targetSdkVersion="8"
      />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TestSamsungS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/buttonTxt"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="buttonTxt">Standard values</string>
    <string name="app_name">TestSamsungS</string>
</resources>
```

res/values-small/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="buttonTxt">Small values</string>
    <string name="app_name">TestSamsungS</string>
</resources>
```

src/org/efalk/testsamsungs/TestSamsungS.java:

```
package org.efalk.testsamsungs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestSamsungS extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Test";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Log.d(TAG, "screen width: " +
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
      Log.d(TAG, "screen height: " +
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
      Log.d(TAG, "density = " + metrics.density);
      Log.d(TAG, "scaledDensity = " + metrics.scaledDensity);
      Log.d(TAG, "widthPixels = " + metrics.widthPixels);
      Log.d(TAG, "heightPixels = " + metrics.heightPixels);
      Log.d(TAG, "xdpi = " + metrics.xdpi);
      Log.d(TAG, "ydpi = " + metrics.ydpi);
    }

    public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using the emulator with no customizations at all.  I don't have access to an actual device at this time, but my question is prompted by a number of customer complaints I've received about my app.

Comment: Also, if folks don't want to compile the code itself, there's an apk at http://www.efalk.org/TestSamsungS.apk